# Index out of range (Table with expandable rows) in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, swift2, uitableview

Hello i am trying to make a shop page on my application. The shop page contains a table with a title that is clickable so it expands into subcategories of that title. Etc click coffee and get some different kind of coffee to buy from.

Title = Drinks, Sandwiches & Drinks in the picture below.

subcategory from title = Ham & cheese, Chicken, bacon & curry .... and so on.

[image: Shop with a expanded title.]

Now the expanding and closing the titles work fine. But when i press + (add iteem to cart) i get a out out of index if it's clicked in a specific order.

if i expand sandwiches (like it is in the picture) and then expand drinks (the one below sandwiches) and then click on the plus on any subcategory in sandwiches and then close sandwiches again and press on plus on any subcategory in Drinks (the one below the now closed sandwiches) the application will crash with a out of index error. Only this combination gives this error.

How the code works:

```
   /*  Create Cells    */
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -
  > UITableViewCell {
    // Row is DefaultCell


    if let rowData = destinationData?[indexPath.row] {
        let defaultCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCellMenuItems", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCellMenuItems

        //            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCellMenuItems", for: indexPath).first as! TableViewCellMenuItems
        defaultCell.menuName.text = rowData.name
        defaultCell.menuPicture.image = rowData.image
        defaultCell.menuFoldPic.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_keyboard_arrow_down")

        defaultCell.selectionStyle = .none
        return defaultCell
    }
        // Row is ExpansionCell
    else {
        if let rowData = destinationData?[getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: indexPath.row)] {
            //            print("her åbner vi")


            //                //  Create an ExpansionCell
            let expansionCell =
                Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCellMenuItemExpanded", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCellMenuItemExpanded

            //  Get the index of the parent Cell (containing the data)
            let parentCellIndex = getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: indexPath.row)


            //  Get the index of the flight data (e.g. if there are multiple ExpansionCells
            let flightIndex = indexPath.row - parentCellIndex - 1

            //  Set the cell's data
            expansionCell.itemPrice.text = String (describing: "\(rowData.menuItems![flightIndex].price) kr")
            expansionCell.itemName.text = rowData.menuItems?[flightIndex].name
            expansionCell.itemCount.text = String (describing: rowData.menuItems![flightIndex].count)
            //                expansionCell.itemCount.text = String (describing: indexPath.row)
            expansionCell.itemAdd.tag = Int(indexPath.row)
            expansionCell.itemMinus.tag = Int(indexPath.row)


            expansionCell.itemAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeSelectedShopViewController.plus(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


            expansionCell.itemMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeSelectedShopViewController.minus(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            expansionCell.selectionStyle = .none
            return expansionCell
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

as you can see the expansionCells get a tag for my function plus and minus (so i can know which indexPath i should add up or down)

Plus function:

```
 func plus(_ sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let rowData = destinationData?[getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: sender!.tag)] {

        self.table.reloadData()

        //  Get the index of the parent Cell (containing the data)
        let parentCellIndex = getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: sender!.tag)


        //  Get the index of the flight data (e.g. if there are multiple ExpansionCells
        let flightIndex = sender!.tag - parentCellIndex - 1

        print(sender!.tag)
        print(flightIndex)
        print(rowData.menuItems!.count)

        var con = 0;
        for a in rowData.menuItems! {
            print("her er navn : \(a.name) og her er id  \(con)")
            con += 1
        }

        let data = rowData.menuItems![flightIndex]

        let item = Items(name: data.name, price: data.price, count: data.count)


        var counter = 0;
        for x in self.basket {

            if(x.name == item.name || x.price == item.price)
            {
                counter = counter+1;
            }

        }

        if(counter >= 99)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.basket.append(item)

                self.updateBasket()
                rowData.menuItems![flightIndex].count = rowData.menuItems![flightIndex].count+1;
                self.table.reloadData()

            }
        }


    }

}
```

Rest of the functions:

```
/*  Expand cell at given index  */
private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    //        print("when is this run 1")
    // Expand Cell (add ExpansionCells
    if let flights = destinationData?[index]?.menuItems {
        for i in 1...flights.count {
            destinationData?.insert(nil, at: index + i)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0) as IndexPath] , with: .top)
        }
    }
}

/*  Contract cell at given index    */
private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    //        print("when is this run 4")
    if let flights = destinationData?[index]?.menuItems {
        for i in 1...flights.count {
            destinationData?.remove(at: index+1)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: index+1, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .top)

        }
    }
}

/*  Get parent cell index for selected ExpansionCell  */
private func getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: Int) -> Int {
    //        print("when is this run 5")
    var selectedCell: Menu?
    var selectedCellIndex = expansionIndex


    while(selectedCell == nil && selectedCellIndex >= 0) {
        selectedCellIndex -= 1
        selectedCell = destinationData?[selectedCellIndex]
    }

    return selectedCellIndex
}

func minus(_ sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let rowData = destinationData?[getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: sender!.tag)] {
        //  Get the index of the parent Cell (containing the data)
        let parentCellIndex = getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: sender!.tag)


        //  Get the index of the flight data (e.g. if there are multiple ExpansionCells
        let flightIndex = sender!.tag - parentCellIndex - 1

        let data = rowData.menuItems![flightIndex]

        let item = Items(name: data.name, price: data.price, count: data.count)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {


            var counter = 0;
            for x in self.basket {

                if(x.name == item.name || x.price == item.price)
                {
                    if(item.count == 0)
                    {
                        break
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.basket.remove(at: counter)
                        self.updateBasket()
                        rowData.menuItems![flightIndex].count = rowData.menuItems![flightIndex].count-1;
                        self.table.reloadData()

                        break
                    }

                }
                counter = counter+1;
            }

        }
    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let data = destinationData?[indexPath.row] {

        // If user clicked last cell, do not try to access cell+1 (out of range)
        if(indexPath.row + 1 >= (destinationData?.count)!) {


            expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
        }
        else {
            // If next cell is not nil, then cell is not expanded
            if(destinationData?[indexPath.row+1] != nil) {

                expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)



            } else {

                contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont really know how to solve this, all i know is that the plus function gets out of range on this bit "let data = rowData.menuItems![flightIndex]".